# Как преобразовать строку в дробное число в библиотеке Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

С помощью библиотеки Tkinter я написал GUI программы, вставил туда поле для ввода Entry

```py
firNumField = Entry(frame, bg='white', font=30)
```

а я записал то что введёт пользователь в переменную строкой кода

```py
result = firNumField.get()
```

то выходит, что если пользователь введёт 123, то result = '123', а нужно result = 123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте встроенную в `python` функцию `float`:

```
result = float(firNumField.get())
```

Однако, вам нужно учесть то, что если пользователь введет то, что к числу не преобразуется (например `Hello`), программа завершит выполнение с ошибкой. Это стоит обработать с помощью блока `try-except`.